# easy3d/core/export.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++

I am trying to use Easy3D library for visualization.I installed library correctly(at least got no errors). I linked it correctly in CmakeLists.txt(No errors here). I try to test it but got error.

Source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <easy3d/core/surface_mesh.h>
#include <easy3d/core/surface_mesh_builder.h>
#include <easy3d/util/initializer.h>

int main(){
   std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
   return 0;
};
```

And the error is :

```
fatal error: easy3d/core/export.h: No such file or directory
[build]    30 | #include <easy3d/core/export.h>
```

I checked the folders and there is no export.h anywhere(I could not find it). It is included in some of the functions aswell. What did I do wrong?

Comment: At least on the main branch in [Easy3D github](https://github.com/LiangliangNan/Easy3D/tree/main/easy3d/core), there is no file `export.h` in `core`. What file does the error `fatal error: easy3d/core/export.h: No such file or directory` originate from?

Comment: 5 mins after posting this question here I  solved it. The reason behind the error was in Cmake. I was not linking it correctly (although i  did not get any errors on that). I looked at https://github.com/LiangliangNan/Easy3D and followed the instructions there.

Comment: it was coming from easy3d/core/types.h . Interesting thing is that export.h is in build (Release) folder and it is not on github.

Comment: @OmarFaig There might be some code-generation phase which creates it before the actual build is started. Just a guess though.